Number of runs needed for Probability of Improvement metric in Deep RL
I'm working with the Probability of Improvement (POI) metric described in [1], Section 4.3.
The paper introduces various aggregate metrics in Section 4.3, and for most of these metrics (IQM, mean, median, optimality gap), they specify using between 3-11 runs per game, with 5 runs being standard for most algorithms (except M-IQN with 3 runs and DreamerV2 with 11 runs).
However, when discussing POI, specifically defined as:
$P(X > Y) = \frac{1}{M} \sum_{m=1}^M P(X_m > Y_m)$
where $P(X_m > Y_m)$ is the probability that algorithm X outperforms algorithm Y on task m, the paper doesn't explicitly state the required number of runs.
Given that POI compares each run from algorithm X with each run from algorithm Y, I'm trying to determine:
What is the minimum number of runs needed per algorithm for a statistically meaningful POI calculation?
How does the number of runs affect the confidence in the POI estimate?
Are there diminishing returns past a certain number of runs?
The related Mann-Whitney U test is mentioned in the paper for this calculation, if that helps inform the answer.
[1]. Agarwal, Rishabh, et al. "Deep reinforcement learning at the edge of the statistical precipice." Advances in neural information processing systems 34 (2021): 29304-29320.

According to Figure 12, it is 10 runs: "...  For all algorithms, results are based on 10 runs per task.". Given that error bars are small, running many more repeats unlikely to change interpretations or returns.

10 runs are still a lot for RL. The other metrics like IQM seemed to only require 3 runs.
